# Formula for calculated column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

The question is:- If an employee is `willing` for an increment and his `experience is more than 2 years`, then the increment rewarded should be `10% of the current CTC(Cost to Company)`. For this, I wrote the formula as

> `Increment` =IF(AND([Willing]="YES",[Experience]>2),([CTC]*1.1),[CTC])
>
> Just for checking I have kept calculated as YES/NO Checkbox. Therefore:- ([CTC]*1.1)= YES and [CTC]= NO.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in the formula? Because no matter what the input is, the output is always "NO".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the Willing is boolean field. Then the below formula works for me.

`=IF(AND(Willing=TRUE,Experience>2),CTC*1.1,CTC)`

Make sure that the calculated column's data type is Number

Comment: 1. Willing is a "Yes/ No (Checkbox Column).
2. Cannot I keep Calculated Column as Currency? Right now I have kept it as YES/ No checkbox  for testing the formula.

Comment: GOT THE ANSWER THANX

Comment: Reading the following answers I replaced "YES" with the boolean value TRUE, and I got the required output. But then again can anyone tell me,

Why it's not working with "YES"?

Comment: Because deep down the value stored is not the TEXT string "YES", SharePoint is very loose about Types, so you even do not need ``=TRUE``. ....................... You want to multiply CTC by 1.1 OR 1 So the Formula can be: ``CTC * IF(AND(Willing,Experience>2) , 1.1 , 1 )``

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
Increment =IF(AND([Willing]=TRUE,[Experience]>2),([CTC]*1.1),[CTC])
```

Comment: GOT THE  ANSWER THANX

Comment: Reading the following answers I replaced "YES" with the boolean value TRUE, and I got the required output. But then again can anyone tell me,

Why it's not working with "YES"?

Comment: the lists does not keep "yes"/"no" string for the checkbox. it keeps true/false

Comment: You can also keep the increment field as currency. better practice is keeping both CTC and Increment as Same Type